# PRIVATEKEYBLOB to RSA struct of OpenSSL

Tags: winapi, openssl

how can i convert Microsoft exported key in privatekeyblob to struct RSA, which can be used with openSSL?

Answer (score 0):

On inspection of the documents, it looks like the fields map across pretty intuitively, one to one.  Have you tried implementing mapping code using this information?  I would give that a go if not.

Here is the [Microsoft blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387401%28VS.85%29.aspx) (linked to [RSAPUBKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387685%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)):

```
typedef struct _RSAPUBKEY {
  DWORD magic;
  DWORD bitlen;
  DWORD pubexp;
} RSAPUBKEY;

BLOBHEADER blobheader;
RSAPUBKEY rsapubkey;
BYTE modulus[rsapubkey.bitlen/8];
BYTE prime1[rsapubkey.bitlen/16];
BYTE prime2[rsapubkey.bitlen/16];
BYTE exponent1[rsapubkey.bitlen/16];
BYTE exponent2[rsapubkey.bitlen/16];
BYTE coefficient[rsapubkey.bitlen/16];
BYTE privateExponent[rsapubkey.bitlen/8];
```

Here is the [RSA struct](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html):

```
 struct
        {
        BIGNUM *n;              // public modulus
        BIGNUM *e;              // public exponent
        BIGNUM *d;              // private exponent
        BIGNUM *p;              // secret prime factor
        BIGNUM *q;              // secret prime factor
        BIGNUM *dmp1;           // d mod (p-1)
        BIGNUM *dmq1;           // d mod (q-1)
        BIGNUM *iqmp;           // q^-1 mod p
        // ...
        };
 RSA
```

Comment: yes, i tried but, did not found BIGNUM *e in that microsoft struct, i tried to get it from RSAPubkey, but was not sucessfull.

Comment: Isn't that `pubexp` in the RSAPUBKEY ?

Comment: hmm maybe, how can i verify that the created result is the right key?

Comment: For private keys the contents are mostly encrypted.  Don't you have test code that you can use to pass in the constructed RSA struct to Open SSL (or to Win32 using a private key blob , depending on which struct you start from)?

Comment: i need to convert from blob to rsa key. When i export the key with win export function with key null param, the blob shouldnt be encrypted. i have nothing to ensure that the converted key is same as it was in blob

Comment: is the DWORD pubexp in little-endien or big?

Comment: Should be little-endian - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386962(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: so, how should i assign it to BIGNUM e? please can you post the code? i am desperate from this. thx

Comment: How have you  converted the individual components of the private key blob structure to big endian. Can u also tell the order in which they are correlated like modulus->n, prime1->p, prime2->q, exponent1->e, exponent2->d, coefficient->dmp1, privateExponent->dmq1